# We need separate hyperledger stack exchange!

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger

What do you guys say? I think we need a new community so that we don't mix hyperledger and ethereum questions.

Comment: Hi there. This is a question for the Meta site -> https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/. Please ask this question there.

Comment: The procedure for requesting new sites is via SE's Area51. Only after the site has been proposed and backed by enough people will it be considered to enter a beta phase. -> https://area51.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Also see this previous related Meta question (from me): https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/555/are-questions-about-hyperledger-fabric-on-topic